# Wordpress, roots meta tags

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering in which file can I add meta tags when using roots wordpress starter theme. I have googled the issue and the standard wordpress theme meta tags can be placed in index.php but in roots theme this did not work.

Comment: To answer my own question the meta tags can be placed in templates/head.php file in roots wordpress startertheme.

Answer (score 1):

Some meta tags are cleaned in roots theme, check the **lib/cleanup.php** file first to check if your meta tag don't be cleaned, if no, for example you can add extra meta tags using this lines in your **lib/custom.php** file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'roots_new_metatag');

function roots_new_metatag() {

  echo "\t<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress 3.9.1\" />\n";
}
```

**lib/cleanup.php** and **lib/custom.php** are included in to **functions.php** file.

and for extra doc with the wp_head action hook, please go to http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head